# Mapping @OneToMany with @JoinFormula as one of the join columns

Tags: java, hibernate, one-to-many, hibernate-mapping, hibernate-onetomany

So I'm trying to map a collection of EntityFieldValue to the EntityRow with one of the join columns being a formula, which **works great for a @OneToOne relation** ('primaryKeyFieldValue' in EntityRow class), but **throws an exception when used in the @OneToMany relation** ('secondaryKeyFieldValues' in EntityRow class).

Hibernate throws a *org.hibernate.MappingException*:

`Unable to find column with logical name: ENTITY_FIELD_ID in org.hibernate.mapping.Table(TBL_ENTITY_ROW) and its related supertables and secondary tables`

Is it possible to make it check join columns existence against the target entity (EntityFieldValue), not the owner entity (EntityRow)? Is it a bug in Hibernate?

Using Hibernate 5.0.10.Final.

Entities:

```
public class Entity {

   @Column(name = "ENTITY_ID", precision = 10)
   private Long entityId;

   ...
}

public class EntityField {

   @Column(name = "ENTITY_ID", precision = 10)
   private Long entityId;

   @Column(name = "ENTITY_FIELD_ID", precision = 10)
   private Long entityFieldId;

   ...
}

public class EntityFieldValue {

   @Column(name = "ENTITY_ID", precision = 10)
   private Long entityId;

   @Column(name = "ENTITY_ROW_ID", precision = 10)
   private Long entityRowId;

   @Column(name = "ENTITY_FIELD_ID", precision = 10)
   private Long entityFieldId;

   ...
}

public class EntityRow {

   @Column(name = "ENTITY_ID", precision = 10)
   private Long entityId;

   @Column(name = "ENTITY_ROW_ID", precision = 10)
   private Long entityRowId;

   @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
   @JoinColumnsOrFormulas({
        @JoinColumnOrFormula(column = @JoinColumn(name = "ENTITY_ID", referencedColumnName = "ENTITY_ID")),
        @JoinColumnOrFormula(column = @JoinColumn(name = "ENTITY_ROW_ID", referencedColumnName = "ENTITY_ROW_ID")),
        @JoinColumnOrFormula(formula = @JoinFormula(value = "( SELECT f.ENTITY_FIELD_ID FROM TBL_ENTITY_FIELD f WHERE f.ENTITY_ID = ENTITY_ID AND f.IS_KEY_FG = 1 )", referencedColumnName = "ENTITY_FIELD_ID"))})
   private EntityFieldValue primaryKeyFieldValue;

   @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
   @JoinColumnsOrFormulas({
        @JoinColumnOrFormula(formula = @JoinFormula(value = "( SELECT f.ENTITY_FIELD_ID FROM TBL_ENTITY_FIELD f WHERE f.ENTITY_ID = ENTITY_ID AND f.SECONDARY_KEY_FG = 1 )", referencedColumnName = "ENTITY_FIELD_ID")),
        @JoinColumnOrFormula(column = @JoinColumn(name = "ENTITY_ID", referencedColumnName = "ENTITY_ID", insertable = false, updatable = false)),
        @JoinColumnOrFormula(column = @JoinColumn(name = "ENTITY_ROW_ID", referencedColumnName = "ENTITY_ROW_ID", insertable = false, updatable = false))})
   private Set<EntityFieldValue> secondaryKeyFieldValues;

   ...
}
```

Full stack trace:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Unable to map collection com.vermilion.vrs.jpa.entity.core.EntityRow.secondaryKeyFieldValues
    at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.CollectionBinder.bindCollectionSecondPass(CollectionBinder.java:1555) [hibernate-core-5.0.10.Final.jar:5.0.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.CollectionBinder.bindOneToManySecondPass(CollectionBinder.java:865) [hibernate-core-5.0.10.Final.jar:5.0.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.CollectionBinder.bindStarToManySecondPass(CollectionBinder.java:780) [hibernate-core-5.0.10.Final.jar:5.0.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.CollectionBinder$1.secondPass(CollectionBinder.java:719) [hibernate-core-5.0.10.Final.jar:5.0.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.CollectionSecondPass.doSecondPass(CollectionSecondPass.java:54) [hibernate-core-5.0.10.Final.jar:5.0.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.processSecondPasses(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:1655) [hibernate-core-5.0.10.Final.jar:5.0.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.processSecondPasses(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:1623) [hibernate-core-5.0.10.Final.jar:5.0.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:278) [hibernate-core-5.0.10.Final.jar:5.0.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:847) [hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.10.Final.jar:5.0.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:874) [hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.10.Final.jar:5.0.10.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.hibernate5.TwoPhaseBootstrapImpl.build(TwoPhaseBootstrapImpl.java:44)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:161) [wildfly-jpa-10.1.0.Final.jar:10.1.0.Final]
    ... 7 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.cfg.RecoverableException: Unable to find column with logical name: ENTITY_FIELD_ID in org.hibernate.mapping.Table(TBL_ENTITY_ROW) and its related supertables and secondary tables
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Ejb3JoinColumn.checkReferencedColumnsType(Ejb3JoinColumn.java:833) [hibernate-core-5.0.10.Final.jar:5.0.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.BinderHelper.createSyntheticPropertyReference(BinderHelper.java:241) [hibernate-core-5.0.10.Final.jar:5.0.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.CollectionBinder.bindCollectionSecondPass(CollectionBinder.java:1545) [hibernate-core-5.0.10.Final.jar:5.0.10.Final]
    ... 18 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Unable to find column with logical name: ENTITY_FIELD_ID in org.hibernate.mapping.Table(TBL_ENTITY_ROW) and its related supertables and secondary tables
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Ejb3JoinColumn.checkReferencedColumnsType(Ejb3JoinColumn.java:828) [hibernate-core-5.0.10.Final.jar:5.0.10.Final]
    ... 20 more
```